# OpenPGP tag 18/19 description confusion Continuation

Tags: implementation, pgp

After coming back to try to finish more of my OpenPGP implementation, I refound one of my  questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021360/openpgp-tag-18-19-description-confusion that I am still having trouble with.

This time however, I have been able to encrypt some data and get another program to decrypt it. The problem is, that I used `tag 9` instead of `tag 18+19`. After rereading the answer to my question, it seemed quite straightforward. Unfortunately, my implementation disagrees with me.

From the answer, it says:

```
MDC_hash = SHA-1(OpenPGP_CFB_extra_data + [plaintext] + "\xd3\x14")
encrypt(OpenPGP_CFB_extra_data + [plaintext] + "\xd3\x14" + MDC_hash)
```

what I am doing:

```
data (ASCII): 0123456789abcdef

after being placed inside a literal data packet:
plaintext = \xcb\x16\x74\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000123456789abcdef 

"generated" prefix for CFB: \x51\x33\xc6\x4b\x4c\x77\x7b\x06\x4c\xfb\x71\xe3\xdd\xfb\xa1\x9f
```

here, tried hashing the data in 2 different ways (i think the correct data to hash is the second version):

```
sha1("\x51\x33\xc6\x4b\x4c\x77\x7b\x06\x4c\xfb\x71\xe3\xdd\xfb\xa1\x9f\xcb\x16\x74\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000123456789abcdef\xd3\x14") = (in hex) 8c2cf8ede9bd851d3dba76363ee32c4ca14e4643

and with the repeated last 2 prefix octets:

sha1("\x51\x33\xc6\x4b\x4c\x77\x7b\x06\x4c\xfb\x71\xe3\xdd\xfb\xa1\x9f\xa1\x9f\xcb\x16\x74\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000123456789abcdef\xd3\x14") = (in hex) 80f570ff8570ed11bea3e2afa826b10c66117fe4
```

then, I do the encryption on:

```
\x51\x33\xc6\x4b\x4c\x77\x7b\x06\x4c\xfb\x71\xe3\xdd\xfb\xa1\x9f\xa1\x9f\xcb\x16\x74\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000123456789abcdef\xd3\x14 + either hash
```

the result I get is PortablePGP/BouncyCastle complaining "unknown object in stream 15".

What am I doing wrong here? Is the error here in my thinking, or somewhere in my unposted code? I am fairly certain that my encrypt function is correct, since, as mentioned above, worked correctly, just not on packet type 18.

Comment: Hello calccrypto and welcome to Crypto SE. This site is about the mathematical concept behind cryptography, so I have migrated your question to StackOverflow.